# Android Samsung SM-G530BT - Black screen after root

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung

I've rooted my Samsung SM-G530BT running Odin3 v3.09. Everything went fine, I've checked and it was rooted as expected. But then I reboot my phone and know it loads the phone model logo but then it shows only a black screen. I've tried all methods to enter Recovery mode and nothing works. What do I have to do in order to restore my device? Is there any software that I can use in my PC to recover? Or even restore the intial settings? Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

> You can recover your device by flashing stock firmware.

First download **stock firmware** for your device from [sammobile.com](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-grand-prime/SM-G530BT/)(or any other site) and then flash it using **Odin** the same way you flashed TWRP or whatever to obtain root.